# XML conversion to CSV with UTF-8

Tags: java, xml, csv, utf-8

I'm trying to flatten XML file to CSV but the result is corrupted and I can't read specific characters (different european languages). Therefore I would like to change the code to specify that the result will be in UTF-8. I found similar case where people suggest using OutputStreamWriter but I am a novice and can't solved out how to rewrite it.

```
try
    {
        PrintWriter pw = null;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;

        if (d_file != null)
        {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(d_file, true);
            pw = new PrintWriter(fos);
        }

        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(d_is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line=null;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            if (pw != null)
            {
                pw.println(line);
            }
        }

        if (pw != null)
        {
            pw.flush();
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you show us some text sample to reproduce the problem?

Comment: <Name><Text>Česká Pošta</Text></Name><StreetName>Karviná, Fryštát</StreetName> <Name><Text>Български пощи</Text></Name><StreetName>Акад. Стефан Младенов</StreetName>

Comment: Does [the list of OutputStreamWriter constructors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#constructor.summary) give you any ideas about what to do?